# Storing images in mat vector

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I am using opencv face detector to locate faces inside an image. I am trying to store the multiple different faces in an vector. It seems that I store the same multiple times. 
Here is my code:

```
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale( gray_image, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE );
    Rect faceRect, eyeRect, temp;
    //draw a rectangle for all found faces in the vector array on the original
    image
    cout<< faces.size()<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
    {
        Point pt1(faces[i].x + faces[i].width, faces[i].y + 
             faces[i].height);
        Point pt2(faces[i].x, faces[i].y);

        rectangle(image, pt1, pt2, cvScalar(0, 255, 0, 0), 3, 8, 0);
        //Create the cropped image
        if(!faces.empty()){
            faceRect = cvRect(faces[i].x, faces[i].y, faces[i].width, faces[i].height);
            croppedFaceImage = gray_image(faceRect).clone();


      resize(croppedFaceImage,resizedcroppedFaceImage,Size(60,60),0,0,INTER_LINEAR);

            char k;
            imshow("new", resizedcroppedFaceImage);
            k = waitKey(0);
            if (k== 'ESC')  {destroyAllWindows();}
            diFaces.push_back(resizedcroppedFaceImage);
        }
        else if(faces.empty()) 
       {resize(gray_image,resizedcroppedFaceImage,Size(60,60),0,0,INTER_LINEAR); break;}
       }
```

When I imshow resizedcroppedFaceImage everything is ok, but when I am trying to imshow diFaces it shows me the same image. Is there any explanation about push_back and storing the same image??

Comment: How do you know `diFaces` stores same images?

Comment: When I imshow(diFaces.at(0)) and imshow(diFaces.at(1)) I get the same image. I should seeing two different images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

since your definition of resizedcroppedFaceImage is *outside* the loop, you indeed reuse the same Mat structure(including the data pointer) for all your images, so they're all the same (pushing them into a vector results a shallow copy only).

so, either push a clone():

```
diFaces.push_back( resizedcroppedFaceImage.clone() );
```

or make resizedcroppedFaceImage a local var inside the loop, so it's a fresh Mat for every pass.